# Testflight: Beta App Review Information not persisting on Appstore connect (distributed via Appcenter)

Tags: continuous-integration, testflight, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

We've integrated with MS AppCenter for our CI needs. It's able to build our application and distribute it to our beta testers via TestFlight.  Up until recently it worked perfectly.  I believe Appstore connect may have received an update on April 7th, but things no longer work as expected.

Each time Appcenter distributes a build to Testflight, the build is flagged due to lack of information and not sent to our testers.  The information it wants is "Beta App Review information" -- essentially contact information for the beta testers.

When I use the side panel on the left hand side of the screen to save this information, it seemingly persists.  However, as soon as the next build is completed and pushed to test flight, the information is erased and, again, the App is not distributed.

My questions: Why is appstore connect not persisting Beta App Review Information? Why do I suddenly need to enter this manually on each push?  Is this related to a recent change to appstore connect?

Comment: Removed the `distribution` tag.  Please read the description before using a tag.

Comment: I suggest filing a bug... https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues

Comment: I have notified AppCenter; it is nice to get confirmation that this is not expected behavior though.  I was wondering if this was the new norm or a limitation imposed by the latest version of appstore connect

Comment: Facing the same issue today, @NickArora did AppCenter clarify what's going on?